# AbstractProcessor, how to claim for annotations which target is another annotation?

Tags: java, java-annotations

Given this annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
public @interface Interceptor {
  Class<? extends Behaviour> value();

}
```

The users of my library can extend its API creating custom annotations annotated with `@Interceptor`, as follows:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Interceptor(BypassInterceptor.class)
public @interface Bypass {
}
```

[AbstractProcessor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html) provides a method called [getSupportedAnnotationTypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html#getSupportedSourceVersion()) which returns the names of the annotation types supported by the processor. But if I specify the name of `@Interceptor`, as follows:

```
 @Override public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
    Set<String> annotations = new LinkedHashSet();
    annotations.add(Interceptor.class.getCanonicalName());
    return annotations;
  }
```

The [processor#process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html#process(java.util.Set,%20javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment)) method will not be notified when a class is annotated with `@Bypass` annotation.

So, when using an `AbstractProcessor`, how to claim for annotations which target is another annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your annotation processor is scanning for all annotations that are meta-annotated with your annotation, you'll need to specify `"*"` for your supported annotation types, and then inspect each annotation's declaration (using `ProcessingEnvironment.getElements()` to determine whether it has the meta-annotation of interest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's exactly what I'm doing now, regardless that the javadoc discourage using it. But I'm stuck trying to retrieve these annotations. Could you please take a look at this another question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040104/how-to-access-an-annotation-inside-another-one-using-abstractprocessor-not-refl

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `@SupportedAnnotationTypes` annotation on your processor, and not override the `getSupportedAnnotationTypes()` method, for example:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({"com.test.Interceptor"})
public class AnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    ...
```

> The Processor.getSupportedAnnotationTypes() method can construct its
>   result from the value of this annotation, as done by
>   AbstractProcessor.getSupportedAnnotationTypes().

Javadoc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/SupportedAnnotationTypes.html