# How to access an annotation inside another one using AbstractProcessor -not reflection

Tags: java

Given these types:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(ANNOTATION_TYPE)
public @interface Annotation1 {

}

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
@Annotation1
public @interface Annotation2 {

}

@Annotation2
public class Mock {

}
```

I'm able to access the `Annotation2` from `Mock` class using an [AbstractProcessor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html), as follows:

```
Element element = //obtained from RoundEnvironment instance.
AnnotationMirror annotationMirror = element.getAnnotationMirrors().get(0);
```

But when I query for the annotations annotated in the pevious annotationMirror- which is a mirror of `Annotation2`, I got an empty list.

```
annotationMirror
    .getAnnotationType()
    .asElement()
    .getAnnotationMirrors();
```

I think somehow this question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036862/abstractprocessor-how-to-claim-for-annotations-which-target-is-another-annotati).

Comment: I think this happens because you've applied `@Annotation2` to a class, which is not a valid target for it - you've specified that the annotation applies only to methods and parameters.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I've updated the question to fix it.

Comment: Why are you trying to get annotations from the `annotationMirror`?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Because I need to create a new java class for every class processed and annotated with an annotation annotated with Annotation1.

Answer (score 2):

The code posted in the question works fine.

```
annotationMirror
    .getAnnotationType()
    .asElement()
    .getAnnotationMirrors();
```

The problem was related with a missing import in the source code used for testing purpose.